Understanding Gregory's argument for the closed orbit condition in the one-body problem
Gregory (Classical Mechanics, 2006) gives the argument below for the condition for a closed orbit in the relatively general case of a spherically-symmetric central force on a particle, $f(r)$ (the "one-body problem").
Now I follow the entire argument (and so I won't include the equations alluded to earlier in the paragraph) up until the point that he says that the orbit will close on itself if  some integer multiple of $\alpha$ is equal to some integral number of full revolutions. In particular, why is it true that

The orbit in the one-body problem is closed if and only if the apsidal angle $\alpha$ is equal to some integral number of full revolutions.

The only if is clear: if the orbit is closed then, starting at some apsidal point and given that we get back to this same point by hypothesis, advance in the trajectory by the apsidal angle some integral number of times $m$ until you get back to the point. In so doing, we will have comleted $n$ revolutions, so $m\alpha = 2\pi n$.
But how do I prove the "if"? Do I argue that after advancing by $m \alpha$ in the orbit I have, by hypothesis, that $\theta$ has returned to the original value and, moreover, that $r$ is back at its initial value since the apsidal angle was defined by starting at (say) a minimum apsidal distance?


Very interesting problem! I did not know that condition.
It is true that the said condition implies a closed orbit, but the reason is not so evident, and it relies on the determinism property of equations of classical mechanics (Newton dynamics). I sketch a proof of this fact.
Consider the Binet variable $u= 1/r$ and the Binet equation, which, as is very well known, is valid for every motion due to a central force. It is given  in the plane normal to the angular momentum of the particle:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}\theta^2} = -\frac{1}{mh^2u^2}F(u^{-1})- u$$
where $h= L/m$, $L$ is the absolute value of the angular momentum of the material point, $m$ its mass, and the known function $F$ accounts for the central force. $\theta \in (-\infty,+\infty)$ is the angle of polar coordinates in the said plane.
That is an autonomous, second-order ODE in normal form. It, therefore, admits an existence and uniqueness theorem for maximal solutions, provided the right-hand side is sufficiently regular (locally Lipschitz, but $C^1$ is sufficient, and I henceforth assume that $F$ is sufficiently regular to assure existence and uniqueness).
More precisely, there exists a unique maximal solution (and all solutions are restrictions of it) if initial conditions $u_0,\dot{u}_0$ are given at some initial angle $\theta_0$:
$$u(\theta_0)= u_0 \quad \mbox{and}\quad \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\Biggr|_{\theta_0}= \dot{u}_0.$$
Furthermore, since the ODE is autonomous ($\theta$ does not explicitly take place on the right-hand side), if $u=u(\theta)$ is a solution, then  $u=u(\theta+ \beta)$ is a solution for every constant $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now suppose that a solution $u$ is provided, with initial conditions at $\theta_0=0$ (we can always choose this initial angle), and we know that at $\theta_1> 0$, for a certain $\theta_1>0$:

$u(\theta_1)= u(0)$;
an apsidal point takes place there: $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\Biggr|_{0}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\Biggr|_{\theta_1}=0$.

Let us focus on the function $U=U(\theta)$ with $\theta \in [0,+\infty)$ defined as follows:
$$U(\theta) := u(\theta) \quad \mbox{if $\theta \in [0, \theta_1]$}$$
$$U(\theta) := u(\theta- 2\theta_1) \quad \mbox{if $\theta \in [\theta_1, 2\theta_1 ]$}$$
$$U(\theta) := u(\theta- 3\theta_1) \quad \mbox{if $\theta \in [2\theta_1, 3\theta_1 ]$}$$
$$(....)$$
According to my comments above, we can say that the following holds.
A) It is periodic of period $\theta_1$.
B) It solves the differential equation in $[0,+\infty)$: it is the translation of a solution so that $t$ is a solution barring the extreme points of continuous intervals. There, however, the branches glue each other up to the second derivative. Indeed, concerning the function and the first derivative, it is obvious by construction; regarding the second derivative, it immediately follows from the differential equation.
C) It satisfies the initial conditions at $\theta_0=0$.
With an analogous argument, we can also extend to $(-\infty, 0]$ the function obtaining a final function $U$ defined on the whole $(-\infty,+\infty)$, still satisfying A, B, C.
Given the uniqueness theorem, it is the solution of the Binet equation with the initial conditions at $\theta_0=0$.
If there are two naturals $n,k$ such that $k\theta_1 =2n\pi$, then the orbit necessarily closes in space after $k$ turns.
What remains to be explained is why $\theta_1 = 2\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between an apsidal point and the subsequent apsidal point (assumed to be of different type).
This is a consequence of the fact that the Binet equation, which I recast to a synthetic form,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}\theta^2} = -G(u)\tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
is autonomous and of the second order. As a consequence, it admits the standard Jacobi first integral
$$J\left(u(\theta),\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right) := 
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^2 + V(u)\tag{2}\label{eq:2}$$
where I defined up to the arbitrary constant $C$,
$$V(u):= \int G(u) \, \mathrm{d}u + C\:.\tag{3}\label{eq:3}$$
(I expect that this type of analysis appears somewhere in Gregory's textbook.) 
In fact, if $u=u(\theta)$ solves $\eqref{eq:1}$, by direct inspection, one sees that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} J\left(u(\theta),\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)  =0\:.$$
As a consequence
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = \pm \sqrt{2J_*- V(u(\theta))}.$$
$J_*$ is constant and determined by the value of $J$ at some angle $\theta_*$ along the considered solution.
Finally
$$\theta = \theta_* \pm \int^{u(\theta)}_{u(\theta_*)} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{ \sqrt{2J_*- V(u(\theta))}}.$$
The analysis of this type of equation is quite standard and shows that the motion in the variable $u$ is always confined between two contiguous solutions $u_{\text{min}}, u_{\text{max}}$ of
$$2J_*- V(u)=0\:.$$
This couple of points defines the two apsidal points. The motion in $\theta$ is necessarily an oscillation between these points. The angular distance between $u_{\text{min}}$ and  $u_{\text{max}}$ is the apsidal angle $\alpha$.
A complete period from an apsidal point to the same apsidal point is, therefore, $2\alpha$ as wanted.

Thank you very much for this very nice answer. I did have one question which perhaps should be obvious to me but is not. Where have you (tacitly?) used the hypothesis that $k \alpha = 2\pi n$ for some $k,n \in \Bbb N$? It seems that in your conditions 1,2 you do use that there is an apsidal point of the same type (say, periapsis) at some $2n \pi$. How does this obtain from the aforementioned hypothesis?

Well, maybe I misundestood the condition. However the only palusible definition of apsidal angle $\alpha$ seemed to me the angle between two consecutive absidal points of the same type. In my answer,  one is located at $\theta_0=0$  (choosing that angle as the origin) and the other at $\theta_1 = 2k\pi$, therefore $\alpha= 2k\pi$.  It seemed to me  the formal translation of  the statement  "α is equal to some integral number of full revolutions." you quoted from the textbook.

Ah, I had understood (per Figure 7.5) that $\alpha$ was the angle between adjacent perihelia and aphelia. At any rate, my understanding of the condition in the last paragraph of the picture is simply that there exist natural numbers $n,m$ such that $m\alpha = 2 \pi n$. I have some vague sense that should imply your 1 and 2, but I just can't quite see how.

You are right! Now I am busy, Later I try to think about how connecting my hypotheses with the one you said.

@EE18 I completed my answer. Notice that in your post you wrote $m\alpha = 2\pi n$, but the right requirement is $m\alpha = \pi n$ for some naturals $n,m$.

Following Gregory's argument more closely. The upshot of his first paragraph is that any section $A_n B_n$ or $B_n A_{n+1}$ can be found from the section $A_1B_1$ by a series of reflections around the apses. In particular, $A_n B_n$ is always going to be obtained by an even number of reflections. Consequently, $A_1B_1$ and $A_n B_n$ are related by a single $SO(2)$ rotation. This implies that if at any point we have that $A_1 =A_n$ then $A_n B_n=A_1B_1$ (and $A_{n+m} \, B_{n+m}=A_{1+m}\,B_{1+m}$ for any integer $m$), i.e. the orbit closes.
Of course, $A_1 =A_n$ if and only if $n 2\alpha = 2\pi m$, i.e. iff $\alpha/\pi$ is a rational number.

I don't quite follow how $A_1 = A_n$ implies that the whole segment $A_nB_n$ then equals $A_1B_1$. I guess you are somehow saying this follows from properties of rotations but I can't quite see how. Is it possible to elaborate on this point?
